# How to copy static files which used internally by node_modules when build a bundle?

Tags: esbuild

I'm building a bundle using Esbuild. However, in many node_modules there are some dependencies that have static files by themselves in their build directory e.g. dist or build dir

How could I bundle or copy those files into my own build dir during the build?